# Is there a way to remove liquidity without calling "_transfer" function inside the CA?

Tags: solidity, uniswap, solidity-0.8.x

Solidity 0.8.16 btw, so overflow returns an error
I put a uint8 variable inside the "_transfer" function, but the variable maxxed out (there were 255 transfers), now no one can transfer anything nor can I remove liquidity on uniswap to relaunch and fix the error... Does anyone have an idea on what I possibly could do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely nothing. Unless there's a way to reset that variable, you're fucked.